# React JS React Query's useMutation: Unable to retrieve the response from the server within the onError callback

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am working on a React JS project. I am using React query, https://react-query.tanstack.com/ to make API requests. I am now having a problem with mutation retrieving the  response data from the server within the onError callback when the API throws 422 or 400 or 401, etc etc.

This is my mutation.

```
let [ createProductMutation, { data, error } ] = useMutation((payload) => createProduct(payload), {
    onMutate: () => {
      
    },
    onSuccess: (response) => {
      
    },
    onError: (err, variables, snapshotValue) => {
      //err is not the response from the server.
    }
  })
```

As you can see in the onError callback, there is no way to retrieve the response from the server.

The data and error (the one next to, createProductMutation) are not the response from the server too.

I tried using this.

```
  try {
       let response = await createProductMutation(data);
        // response from the API is not here too, "response"
    } catch (e) {
        // response from the API is not here too
    }
```

How can I retrieve the response within the onError callback?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I have my react-query separated out into different files to keep modularization. I'm having trouble with returning the error message. Instead of it throwing an error in the console.

Answer (score 3):

```
let [ createItem ] = useMutation(payload => createItem(payload), {
  onError: (error) => {
    console.log(error.response.data);
    console.log(error.response.status);
  }
})
```

For me above solution worked! Inside `onError`, error.response should be available.

Answer (score 2):

To get the response you need to convert the error into json and then await the promise. See the example below with "message" being whatever your backend is returning for the response message.

```
onError: async (error, variables, context) => {
    const errorObj = error;
    const errorObjAsJSON = await errorObj.json();
    const { message } = errorObjAsJSON;
    console.log(message);
  },
```

You can obviously condense that further by

```
onError: async (error, variables, context) => {
        const errorObj = await error.json();
        const { message } = errorObj;
        console.log(message);
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: make sure the function you provide to useQuery is returning a promise

example

```
useQuery('getAllUsersInfo', getAllUsersInfo)
```

make sure that getAllUsersInfo function is returning a promise.

I had this same issue happened to me because the function I provided  to useQuery wasn't returning the promise so react query thought the request is successful while it was actually failing

Comment: plz add more details to your answer, code block and ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).